# Can't connect to internet wirelessly via Linksys router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router, home-networking

I've got a Cisco Linksys E2500 router that we used to use for our home wifi a few years back (we've had an ISP-provided modem/router combo for the past couple years at our last apartment), and I can't connect to the internet wirelessly through it. I'm finally able to connect via a wired connection (the default IP address - `192.168.1.1` - was the same as what the ISP-provided modem uses; changed it to .2 and wired is OK) and get internet access that way, but wirelessly I can only connect to the router without internet access.

When I connect my laptop (<strike>Windows 7</strike> ok apparently Windows 10) wirelessly, I get

> *SSID*
>   connected, no internet

This morning, my Android (Nexus 6, Android 6.0.1) would get stuck on the "Obtaining IP Address..." stage of connection. Now it gets to the same place as the laptop (connected, no internet) before starting the connection attempt all over.

The firmware version of the router is 1.0.0.

I've tried pinging `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2` (the router and the modem, respectively) from my laptop while connected via wifi, and both of them yield

> Reply from 192.168.1.5: Destination host unreachable.
>   Request timed out.

where `192.168.1.5` is the IP address of the laptop when it's connected via Ethernet.

How can I get devices wirelessly connected to the router to access the internet?

Comment: Have you logged in to the router and changed/setup the settings?

Comment: @TimmyJim yes, I've changed the SSID and password, and the password to log into the router.

Comment: Static or DHCP? What browser are you using from Win10?

Comment: Can you log into your router? Is MAC filter enabled and back to question above this one; static or DHCP on router?

Comment: @ejbytes DHCP was disabled. I tried enabling it and rebooting the router; this seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @yoozer8 Cool, glad it worked out! I've posted the answer. Feel free to edit if you think of anything that could help out any future solution seekers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP indicated this was the problem:

- Log into the router and check if MAC filtering is enabled. If so, you
  must enter the MAC address of your new device. Or disable this
  feature if you find that it's not necessary at this point.
- Log into the router and check if static IP or DHCP is being used.

  If you are not using static IP's and haven't entered each IP
  independently then make sure DHCP is enabled in the router and reboot
  the router.